# Xcode Issue - Crash - unable to read property list from file

Tags: swift, xcode

Ive had the following issue come up - error: unable to read property list from file:  The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.
More specifically something with line seven? Ive opened the document and this came up "Failed to open property list: Encountered unexpected element at line 7 (plist can only include one object)"
Im really not sure what has gone wrong but any help would be appreciated!!

The code is the file currently reads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
</dict>
<dict/>
</plist>
```

Comment: Remove the extra <dict/> at line number 8

Comment: Remove unnecessary unused <dict/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<dict/>` line, as this is the second dictionary object it's complaining about. Corrected file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```